# How to declare the Class instance from inside of itself

Tags: python

I would like to declare the `Item` class instance from inside of its own method.
But the code raises the `RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded`.
What caused the error and what should we know to avoid it?

```
class Item(object):
    def __init__(self, arg):
        self.arg = arg    
        self.outputs = []    
        for i in range(5):
            item = Item('Child Item %s' % i)
            self.outputs.append(item)

item = Item('Root item')
```

Comment: You're calling `__init__` inside `__init__`. That then calls `__init__`. Which then calls `__init__`. Which then calls...

Comment: When you create the child items, they run the constructor as well, immediately creating sub-child items, which run their constructors, creating sub-sub-child items, etc.

Comment: You’re creating 5 children for every child, and so on. When do you want to stop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem looks like it is because you are doing this within the constructor which causes your object to infinitely keep creating more of itself.

You must implement some solution for your program to know when it can stop creating additional children.

Answer (score 1):

Something seems pretty wrong with what you are doing here and I encourage you to ask another question about the actual thing it is you are actually trying to accomplish.

But here is one way to force it to work. I do not suggest actually doing it.

```
class Item(object):
    def __init__(self, arg):
        self.arg = arg    
        self.outputs = []    
        for i in range(5):
            item = Item.__new__(Item, 'Child Item %s' % i)
            item.arg = i
            self.outputs.append(item)

item = Item('Root item')
```

Note that the child instances don't have `child.outputs` attributes. Should they? If so, what should be in them...? If not, are they really REALLY `Item` instances...?

Answer (score 0):

Don't declare an `Item` class instance from inside of its own `__init__` method. Here is one of many possible solutions:

```
class Item(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.children = None

    def getChildren(self):
        if self.children is None:
            self.children = [Item('Child Item %s' % i) for i in range(5)]
        return self.children

item = Item('Root item')
print item.getChildren()
```